# Determine where user came from when address is manually entered

Tags: php, http, referer

I know you can get the HTTP referer when someone enters your page by clicking a link to it. But is it also possible to determine what page a user is on when they type the address themselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard, the browser MUST NOT send the address of the current page when an address is entered by the user. From the [HTTP/1.1 header field documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36):

> The Referer field MUST NOT be sent if the Request-URI was obtained from a source that does not have its own URI, such as input from the user keyboard.

---

Below is my previous answer, which didn't exactly match the question, but I've left it here for history purposes.

> The referrer would be empty (or non-existent) if the address is typed directly into the browser, but that's not really something you can rely on (i.e. the referrer could be empty for other reasons).
>
> One notable reason for the referrer to be empty is when a browser switches from secure to non-secure mode.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some obscure browser that sends whatever URL the user was on as HTTP REFERER when he/she typed your URL (or clicked a bookmark), but generally no.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to get referrer directly from keyboard

If Its the same `domain` & `system` you can use `Permanent Cookies` as a simple workaround

Example

```
   setcookie("lastLink"  ,$value, mktime (0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2020));
```

Anytime the user comes back you can retrieve the last link  `$_COOKIE['lastLink']`